# Create Pentaho metadata Domain via API: Exception 'Properties ... not initialised!'

Tags: java, pentaho

I am trying to create a Pentaho metadata Domain via the Java class . When creating a Data Model using Pentaho automodel API, I run into an exception.

Is initialization other than `KettleEnvironment.init();` (which I have executed) required?

Please suggest how to resolve the exception:

Root cause: Code referenced from Props.java at http://trac.spatialytics.com/geokettle/browser/trunk/src-core/org/pentaho/di/core/Props.java. However Props constructor is protected, not public , so I can't instantiate it.

```
public static Props getInstance()
        {
                if (props!=null) return props;

                throw new RuntimeException("Properties, Kettle systems settings, not initialised!");
        }
```

However Props constructor is protected, not public , so I can't instantiate it. The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.pentaho.pms.core.exception.PentahoMetadataException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Properties, Kettle systems settings, not initialised!
    at org.pentaho.metadata.automodel.AutoModeler.generateDomain(AutoModeler.java:127)
    at org.abc.poc.AutoModelerScenario.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.abc.poc.MyApplication.main(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Properties, Kettle systems settings, not initialised!
    at org.pentaho.di.core.Props.getInstance(Props.java:229)
    at org.pentaho.pms.util.Settings.getBusinessTableIDPrefix(Settings.java:46)
    at org.pentaho.metadata.util.Util.proposeSqlBasedLogicalTableId(Util.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.metadata.automodel.AutoModeler.createBusinessTable(AutoModeler.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.metadata.automodel.AutoModeler.generateDomain(AutoModeler.java:121)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, besides `KettleEnvironment.init();`, you need to invoke `org.pentaho.di.ui.core.PropsUI.init(Display d, String filename)`. E.g.

`PropsUI.init(new Display(), System.getenv("user.home") + "/.kettle/.spoonrc");`

You may also ensure all Pentaho ui\images folder is available when you run your code.

Answer (score 1):

It works, but for further versions you need:

```
PropsUI.init(new Display(), System.getenv("user.home") + "/.pentaho-meta/.pme-rc");
```